# Read ints from txt file java error

Tags: java, file, int

Can you tell me what's the problem? I'm trying to read integers from the file named "tablica.txt" and it looks like that in a file: 8 3 2 1 4 3 2

```
package Operacje_na_plikach;

import jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.WhileNode;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Zad1 {
    /*
    Plik tekstowy ‘tablica.txt’ ma postać: 8 3 2 1 4 3 2 Pobierz liczby z pliku tekstowego do tablicy i wypisz na ekranie sumę elementów tej tablicy.
     */
    public static int[] odczyt(String nazwa) {
        int[] arr = null;
        try {
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(nazwa);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(reader);
            int d = sc.nextInt();
            int suma = 0;
            arr = new int[d];
            for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
                arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
                suma += arr[i];
            }

            sc.close();
            reader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arr;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = odczyt("tablica.txt");
        if (arr != null) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException   at
>   java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)     at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)  at
>   java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)  at
>   Operacje_na_plikach.Zad1.odczyt(Zad1.java:27)     at
>   Operacje_na_plikach.Zad1.main(Zad1.java:42)

Answer (score 1):

Your code uses the first number to determine how many numbers to read.

If you don't know how many numbers you will need to read, you could use an ArrayList and the function Scanner.hasNextInt() as follows:

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while(scan.hasNextInt()) {
    int d = scan.nextInt();
    arr.add(d);
    suma += d;
}
```

An ArrayList is an array that automatically expands to store numbers and scan.hasNextInt() checks whether there are more numbers left to read.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is reading the first number, and then using that value to determine how many more numbers to read.

Your input is `8 3 2 1 4 3 2`, so your program reads the `8`, and then tries to read 8 more numbers.

Since there are only 6 more numbers, when you try to read the 7th you get an error.

Comment: how to define length of an array in that case, i mean when i'll change the input it will always make a proper length of this array